# Overhead of using structs as wrappers for primitives for type-checking?

Tags: c#

Let's say I want to get extra type-checking for working with primitives that mean different things semantically:

```
public struct Apple
{
    readonly int value;

    // Add constructor + operator overloads
}

public struct Orange
{
    readonly int value;

    // Add constructor + operator overloads
}
```

The point is we can't compare "apples to oranges", so wrapping up the actual int in a struct means we get type checking and some extra readability and documentation by code.

My question is: what is the overhead associated with doing this, both in terms of memory and speed? Since structs are value types, would variables containing these structs be 32 bits or larger? What about performance overhead of using these structs instead of primitives - is there a large overhead for the operator overloads?

Any other advice on the wisdom of doing this?

Comment: Not performance related, but I used an approach like this recently, and got bitten by the fact that structs force you to have a default empty constructor you don't control, which means that you can't prevent a zero-apple from being created.

Comment: In my particular case 0 values are fine, but good thing to keep in mind in general. The same thing can be done for ints though, so that is not really a comparative drawback (compared to primitives), but a limitation to keep in mind.

Comment: The default constructor issue can usually be mitigated by using private members to store the values and properties with logic in the getters (rather than the setters) to check for default(T) and replace it with the desired value. Boolean flags with the "wrong" default can be mitigated by having the internal member store the opposite of the interface's meaning. But I agree, this is a pain in C# and really shouldn't be.

Comment: Upvoted because I want to know the answer too, and for "can't compare apples to oranges" :) Did you ever find out about performance overhead? My hope would be that the overhead is all syntactic sugar that would evaporate at compile time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In memory there is no overhead using a struct which you can verify using  `Marshal.SizeOf()`:

```
struct testStruct
{
    public readonly int value;
}
..

int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(testStruct)); //returns 4
```

This also is the same as returned by `sizeof(testStruct)`:

```
unsafe
{
    int size = sizeof(testStruct); //returns 4
}
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) the difference between the two sizing methods is:

> Although you can use the
>   Marshal.SizeOf method, the value
>   returned by this method is not always
>   the same as the value returned by
>   sizeof. Marshal.SizeOf returns the
>   size after the type has been
>   marshaled, whereas sizeof returns the
>   size as it has been allocated by the
>   common language runtime, including any
>   padding.

Comment: That's good to know. I had wondered if that were the case. And thanks for the tips on figuring out size of objects. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

I'll probably get shunned for this, but you *could* do:

```
using Apple = System.Int32;
using Orange = System.Int32;
```

You won't be able to use it across files. And technically you can still compare apples to oranges.

Comment: Helps (a bit) with readability, but doesn't address the OP's desire for type-checking.